# An example of a simple higher-order function in javascript

Tags: javascript

While going through [Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 6)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html) there is a reference to higher-order functions in Javascript. While there is an example provided in Chapter 3, I believe it could be a bit simpler since I still don't fully understand the concept. After searching the web I can't seem to find any succinct examples of a higher-order function.

I'd like to see a basic/simple higher-order function in Javascript that will explain the concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Higher functions are concepts from [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). In briefly, a higher function is a function which takes another function as parameter. In javascript, some higher functions are added recently.

```
Array.prototype.reduce 
//With this function, we can do some funny things.
function sum(array){
    return array.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0);
}
```

So, in the above sample, `reduce` is a higher order function, it takes another function, the anonymous function in the sample, as a parameter. The signature of `reduce` looks like this

```
reduce(func, init);
//func is a function takes two parameter and returns some value.
// init is the initial value which would be passed to func
//when calling reduce, some thing happen

//step 1.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b }, 0);
//step 2.
[2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b}, 0 + 1);
//step 3.
[3, 4, 5].reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b}, 0 + 1 + 2);
//...
```

As you can see, `reduce` iterate an array, and apply the `func` with `init` and first element of that array, then bind the result to `init`.

Another higher order funciton is `filter`.

```
Array.prototype.filter
//As the name indicates, it filter out some unwanted values from an Aarry. It also takes a function, which returns a boolean value, true for keeping this element.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(function(ele){ return ele % 2 == 0; });
```

With the above two examples, I have to say higher order function is not that much easy to understand, especially `reduce`. But that's not *complex*, with higher order function, actually your code would be more clean and readable. Take the `filter` as example, it tells people that it throws all odd numbers away.

Here I'd like to implement a simple `filter` function to show you how.

```
function filter(array, func){
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(func(array[i])) output.push(array[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it has really helped me understand things more!